# Strange Distillation Behavior

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, heat, distillation, decomposition

I was attempting a fractional distillation with 1mL water and 1mL propylene glycol, and I’ve been encountering strange behavior with the heating of the mixture. The heating curve shows strange “spikes” in temperature rather than a continuous heating curve. I have ran a standard water and ethanol distillation to check for defects in my laboratory equipment, but the curve for that looks completely normal, and it seems to me like the equipment isn’t the issue. I would love any possible help in explaining this abnormality.

[image: Abnormal Heating Curve]

Comment: Can you describe the equipment and what item is having its temperature monitored and what kind of thermometer? Are you using vacuum? Vigreaux column? Spinning band?

Comment: The issue might be that distilling one liter and one milliliter is indeed different at least in controlling the T.

Comment: Can we know more about the placement of the thermometer?